# Pi using Monte Carlo on Circular Crown (an Annulus)

Tags: monte-carlo

I am a computer science student and I am currently studying (for *fun* if you could say that) during my college break, I was implementing a simple program to calculate pi using the Monte Carlo method by counting the points inside a circle,it worked as it should, the I thought if it would be possible to do the same using a circular crown (or, as pointed out by comments an annulus) instead of a circle (which I pretty much believe it is) but the simulation always converges to around 2.8, what I did is:

1. Calculate the area of the circular crown
2. Write the probability of a point being within it as the ratio of it's area and the rectangle around it (whatever it's size may be)
3. Then isolate pi in the equation
4. Run the simulation (ie.:Sample random points) count them and calculate pi

I triple checked my algebra and it's seems to be right, am I missing or did not undertand something about the method?

Just in case I made any mistake with the algebra, I will leave it here:

The area of a circular crown is given by $$A_{crown} = \pi(a^2-b^2)$$ where $a$ is the external radius and $b$ is the internal radius, here $a=r+\epsilon$ and $b=r-\epsilon$, we can then calculate the probability of a point being within the crown as $$P_{crown} = \dfrac{A_{crown}}{A_{rectangle}}$$
We have $A_{crown} = \pi(a^2-b^2) \rightarrow A_{crown} = \pi(a-b)(a+b)$, since $a-b=2\epsilon$ then $A_{crown}=2\pi\epsilon(a+b)$ also $a+b=2r$ and then $A_{crown}=2\pi\epsilon2r$ changing $2\epsilon$ for $w$ we have $A_{crown}=2wr\pi$ this gives us $\dfrac{A_{crown}}{A_{rectangle}} = P_{crown}$ which in turn gives
$$\pi = \dfrac{P_{crown}A_{rectangle}}{2rw}$$

Comment: What is a circular crown?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by *crown*. I'm guessing you're referring to an [*annulus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) but you should be explicit.

Comment: Sorry I will edit, I just translated it literally from my native language

Comment: Your algebra seems OK. Are you sure your implementation is correct ? Especially is your annulus of inner diameter $r-w/2$ and outer $r+w/2$ ?

Comment: Yes, I did it by checking $1-\epsilon \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le 1+\epsilon$

Comment: I didn't see you carry out the procedure you outlined in the beginning, so maybe the problem is you aren't following your strategy.  Since "the ratio of its area and the rectangle around it" is $\pi(a^2-b^2)/(4a^2)$, your estimate of $\pi$ will be the proportion of points in the annulus multiplied by $4a^2/(a^2-b^2)$. Are you trying to tell us this is always close to $2.8$?? If so, the problem lies in your implementation.

Comment: I've got it, when I add a width to the annulus, part of it gets clipped from the simulation because it's off the limit's of the coordinates I am sampling, since this lost area is smaller for the annulus than for the rectangle the quotient should be smaller, when I added the $\epsilon$ to each side of the rectangle the simulation converged to the expected value